# Select an area of bitmap with specific color

Tags: android, image, colors, bitmap

I have a bitmap and I need to find some area of it with specified color (red, for example).

I know that I can simply use **bitmap.getPixels()** to get image's matrix and query it for some area of pixel.

Can anybody provide me for an algorithm of this task?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the color of every pixel you could do it this way:

```
for(int i=0;i<bitmap.getWidth();i++){
for(int j=0;j<bitmap.getHeigth();j++){
    int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(i,j);
    if(pixel == Color.RED){
        //Do something
    }
}
 }
```

If you want to get a more wider area,you should use matrix instead,or draw a rectangle and get the values inside there!